# Jest testing with angular ionic storage is failing

Tags: jestjs, ionic5, ts-jest, angular11

Hi i am using angular 11 and ionic 5 ;

for ionic storage i am using @ionic/storage-angular:^3.0.6 module.

during jest unit tests i am getting

> Cannot find module '@ionic/storage' from
> 'node_modules/@ionic/storage-angular/bundles/ionic-storage-angular.umd.js'

@ionic/storage-angular is a dependency in one of the service which i mocked

jest.confi.js has

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    './node_modules/(?!@ionic|ngx-socket-io/|!@ionic/storage-angular)'
]
```

spec file mocking the service

```
let storeServiceStub={
  get:jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({})
};

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DataSyncComponent ],
      providers:[
        { provide: StoreService, useValue: storeServiceStub },
      ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

@ionic/storage-angular is a of store service which i m replacing with stub;

testing env to repo bug
package.json

```
dependencies:{
  ...
  "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
  ...
}
devDependencies:{
  ...
  "jest": "^27.0.3",
  "jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.1",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
  ...

}
```

node v 14
os osx 11.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can fix it by adding the following configuration in my jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@ionic/storage': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@ionic/storage/dist/esm/index.d.ts',
    },
```

Quite similar to the answer from @Ferraria. But the module name starts with the character ^ and the path ends in index.d.ts.

My complete configuration is

```
module.exports = {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|@ionic-native|@ionic)"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@ionic/storage': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@ionic/storage/dist/esm/index.d.ts',
    },
    setupFiles: ["jest-canvas-mock"]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the jest moduleNameMapper for @ionic/storage in your jest.config.js like this:

```
    ...,
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      './node_modules/(?!@ionic|ngx-socket-io/|!@ionic/storage-angular)'
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@ionic/storage": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@ionic/storage/dist/esm"
    }
```

You can find more information for moduleNameMapper [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring).

Comment: i tried this i am getting ` SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module for a localforge which is dependency of @ionic/storage-angular`